# Showing progress in Google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, notifications

I want to show progress of a lengthy script to the user. Ideally I want to use the yellow toast that comes up saying `running script cancel dismiss` when running a Google script

I know u can throw custom error but how can throw custom messages to this yellow box.

Or another alternative will do as well. Not msgbox as that stops the script.

Comment: See the following Stack Overflow answer: [Link to Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24436445/2946873)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using the spreadsheet class of toast:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('message')`

Comment: How is the toast closed? How does it know the long running script has completed?

Comment: To know how long a running script has prolonged, you have to update the toast message with a variable count, like the following:    .toast(`PROGRESS: Math.round(${count} / 7*100) `); or any other way like showing "7 out of 100" instead of percentages. Create a new thread if this still confuses you, but the above solution is correct. EDIT: use backticks (`) instead of quote marks to include ${} string interpolation syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would think htmlService would work for you:

```js
function function1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var htmlApp = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('Your Message')
     .setTitle("Progress")
     .setWidth(750)
     .setHeight(220);

 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);

}
```

Comment: How would I update the creahtmloutput part during the code or would it have to be copying and pasting this code everytime

Comment: Thanks for your answer it opened door to a new area, coincedently i called my function toast and it just so happens there is a spreadsheet class called toast! Which practically does what I need it to do. Thanks a lot