# google.script.run while executing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking to show a spinner while a google script is running. How can one get the state to know if the script is running?

here is my code so far:

```
//I did this way so I can pass a variable to the run script function

   var somescript = "google.script.run.foo_"+bar+"()";

   var func = new Function (somescript);

   return(func());
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/24415870/7108653

Comment: actually, this worked! Thank you very much both!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved by that thread.